# Email.js:247 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

`When ever I click on the particular data on the list the data is consoled only for the params. And it is not setting that data for selectedRow and also not consoling this part` if (!selectedRow) {
}

const handleRowClick = (params) => {
`if (params?.data?.id === undefined) { //   console.error("Invalid params.data or params.data.id is undefined"); console.log("Params:", params.row.name); console.log("Params:", params); console.log("Email Templates:", emailTemplates); }` Only for this part

```
const selectedRow = emailTemplates.find((template) => {
  const templateId = template.id; // Ensure template.id is of the same type as params.data.id
  return templateId === params.data.id;
});

if (!selectedRow) {
  console.error("Selected template not found");
  console.log("Params:", params.row.name);
  console.log("Params:", params);
  console.log("Email Templates:", emailTemplates);
  return;
}

setSelectedTemplate(selectedRow);
console.log("Selected Template:", selectedRow);
```

};

Params: Onboarding
Email.js:241 Params: {id: 1, columns: Array(2), row: {…}}
Email.js:242 Email Templates: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
2Email.js:247 Uncaught `TypeError`: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at Email.js:247:1

If i click on the data on the list it is consoling the params part nut not the `setSelectedTemplate` part.`

Comment: - Check if params and params.data are defined before accessing` params.data.id`
-Debug the params object: It might be helpful to understand what the params object looks like.
- Ensure that params.data is being set correctly
Remember, debugging is a process of verifying assumptions and narrowing down the parts of your code that could be causing the issue